# Mouse does not click in the focused window but the oldest window

Tags: 14.04, xorg, compiz, mouse

I'm on 14.04, `lsusb` shows my USB mouse on the list as `Mad Catz, Inc`

The mouse pointer can be moved smoothly and well but button clicks are a mess.

Another example: I am operating on a browser (e.g. Firefox), working perfectly well, except for the minimize/maximize/close buttons in the top left corner. Then I start a program, let's say terminal, which is on top of my browser. At this point terminal is in the foreground, which my keyboard agreed with me since I can type here. However, my mouse is not quiet on the same page: it still operates on the Firefox browser!

And I cannot bring any application to foreground by mouse clicking, only <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> works.

What is the problem? Hardware? Mouse raycast? Sensor? Any idea?

P.S. I tried to update the `xorg` and drivers but the problem remains.

Comment: I even did an upgrade to ubuntu 15 and the mouse problem remains. i tried different mouse and has the same problem.. the OS works fine on my other computer.. so hardware problem? motherboard Asus p8z77-v pro, don't think other parts matters but still: evga gtx660 ti, 8g ddr3, i5-3450

Comment: Well the problem actually can be solved by replacing my mouse.

Answer (score -2):

An extra display under **System Settings => Display** is causing the error.

You have to disabled it.