# Mouse clicks stop registering in some windows

Tags: unity, mouse

Yesterday and today I have been struggling with a strange problem: in **some** windows, the mouse **clicks** are ignored:

Symptoms:

- The pointer is fine, the keyboard is fine, but I can neither left- nor right-click. Moving the pointer to another window, it works fine again.
- Affected windows include Chrome - and the Unity launcher itself!
- After another reboot, I could operate Unity and Chrome. But when I then launched Gedit, Gedit didn't want my clicks - and then Chrome didn't see them anymore either (until the next reboot)!
- For each affected window, it's the *entire* window including borders, menus, close button, scroll bars, everything. Each such window can still be operated with the keyboard, but only as far as keyboard shortcuts that are offered, and faux-mouse navigation using tab+space.

  - update: it seems that the clicks go *through* the active window and hit the one behind! I couldn't click in the browser, but when I double-clicked, I noticed that a text line in the terminal window behind the browser was highlighted.

Things I've already tried, yet the problem persists:

- searched Askubuntu for similar problems,
- a round of update&upgrade&reboot,
- replaced the mouse batteries,
- because the mouse works just fine in some windows, I'm ruling out a hardware problem,
- reboot again and struggle on until the problem happens again,
- reboot into a live 17.10 from a USB stick,  ...

Help!?

- wait a minute: if the problem persists even on an USB live version then it's not my installation, then it must be the mouse!
- I switched to an old wireless mouse&USB dongle (using the AA batteries from the previous mouse!) and that seems to work just fine! But then *how in the world* could the previous mouse click *through* the active window??
- I want my good mouse back

I'm running a plain 16.04 without problems since it was released. I use a Logitech M705 wireless mouse and a Logitech K230 wireless keyboard on a shared USB dongle.

Comment: Exactly the same reported here https://askubuntu.com/questions/662789/mouse-does-not-click-in-the-focused-window-but-the-oldest-window and most likely the same here https://askubuntu.com/questions/588646/mouse-clicks-stop-registering-in-some-or-all-windows

Comment: I have the exact same problem on 16.04. Changing the mouse solves the problem but it seems insane because I was working with the "bad" mouse for many months. Unplugging/replugging/changing USB port and similar voodoo don't work. You can get a few minutes of relief by switching to/from text console (ctrl-alt-f1, then ctrl-alt-f7). The mouse that gives me problems is a Microsoft Sculpt Ergonomic Mouse. An old Microsoft Wheel Mouse Optiocal works fine.

Comment: I think this is because of your ram running out. Happens to me sometimes too. And sometimes it takes down my whole OS.

Comment: @KhushrajRathod nope - I've never used up all 16GB RAM on my machine...